# How to specify the cell in column M of the active row?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I need to figure out how to tell VBA to go to the cell in column M of the current row and change the number format to `0.00` if the criteria are met.  However, the other cells in the current row must stay with `0` number format.  Here is the code so far:

```
Sheets("xxx").Activate
With Sheets("xxx")
    For Lrow = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        With .Cells(Lrow, "J")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If .Value = "Desk to adjust" Then
                    Sheets("xxx").UsedRange.Rows(Lrow).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
                    Sheets("xxx").UsedRange.Rows(Lrow).NumberFormat = "0"
                End If
                If .Value = "Desk to adjust" Then
                    Sheets("xxx").Range("M" & ActiveCell.Row).Select.NumberFormat = "0.00"
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
End With
```

The error I am getting is with this IF:

```
If .Value = "Desk to adjust" Then
   Sheets("xxx").Range("M" & ActiveCell.Row).Select.NumberFormat = "0.00"
End If
```

Comment: You are referring to ActiveCell.Row, when it's not clear what the Active Cell actually is. Remember an Active Cell is either (1) the cell you manually click on in Excel; or (2) the cell in VBA which has .Select written to it. ie: Range("A1").Select - in generally don't refer to the Active cell anyway. Here, try referring to just Lrow, instead of ActiveCell.Row.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon You're a legend. Problem solved.  Thank you sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the note in my comment worked (I assumed there was something deeper going on), I'll put this as an answer so you can mark as accepted and close the question:

You are referring to ActiveCell.Row, when it's not clear what the Active Cell actually is. Remember an Active Cell is either (1) the cell you manually click on in Excel; or (2) the cell in VBA which has .Select written to it. ie: Range("A1").Select - in generally don't refer to the Active cell anyway. Here, try referring to just Lrow, instead of ActiveCell.Row.